# searching arrays with vbs

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to search through an array for a printer and if the printer exists display the name in the HTA. That bit works ok, but when no printer is found in the array all the installed printers on the device are displayed. is there a way to only show printers that are found

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
arrPrinters = Split(objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Windows\DEW\denied-printers.txt" ,ForReading).ReadAll(), VbCrLf)

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
For Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
    localprinter = objPrinter.Name
    For Each strLine in arrPrinters
        If inStr(localprinter,strLine) > 0 Then 
            strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td>" & localprinter & "</td></tr>"
    End If 
Next
Next
```

Comment: Unless your code is not complete, do you think the "Next" match all the "For"??

Comment: I've cut the code out of a 1200 line script. Missed one of the next's out

Comment: try this

    If inStr(localprinter,strLine) > 0 OR inStr(localprinter,strLine) = NULL Then

Comment: the problem is if array is empty, strline is NULL and when you used it in inStr, it returns NULL instead of '0'. That is one possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
If inStr(localprinter,strLine) > 0 OR inStr(localprinter,strLine) = NULL Then 

End If
```

the problem is if array is empty, strline is NULL and when you used it in inStr, it returns NULL instead of '0'. That is one possibility – tunmise fasipe 3 mins ago edit

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem - i guess without knowing the contents of yoyr file - is that in instr(textToSearch, searchString) you switch the two parameters .
Anyway, here a version of your code i tested.

```
const ForReading = 1
strComputer = "."
set objFSO = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
printers = objFSO.OpenTextFile("denied-printers.txt" ,ForReading).ReadAll()
set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
for Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters
   localprinter = objPrinter.Name
   if instr(printers, localprinter) then
     strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td>" & localprinter & "</td></tr>"
   end if
next
```

EDIT: here the stand alone vbscript version, save it to a .vbs file and run to test

```
on error resume next
const ForReading = 1 
strComputer = "." 
file = "denied-printers.txt"
set objFSO = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
if err.number=0 then
  printers = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file ,ForReading).ReadAll()
  if err.number=0 then
    set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
    set colInstalledPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer") 
    for Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters 
       localprinter = objPrinter.Name 
       if instr(printers, localprinter) then 
         wscript.echo localprinter & " found in " & file
       end if 
    next 
  else
    wscript.echo "file " & file & " not found, showing all printers"
    for Each objPrinter in colInstalledPrinters 
      wscript.echo objPrinter.Name
    next 
  end if
else
  wscript.echo "Error" & err.description
end if
```

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't display the printer if it finds it in the array.

Comment: the script itself ddidnt show anything, it merely add's TR and TD tags which only have sense in a clientside script when you use document.write or response.write in a serverside script, in case of problems i advise to first make your script work as a simple .vbs script and when it works, include it in your html, asp or what so ever, i add such a version with some error trapping